# Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object, why?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

I wrote this code:

```
function GetIds($forum_id,$from_page,$to_page) {
$ids = array();
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
for($i = $from_page; $i <= $to_page; $i++){
    $dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.example.com/forumdisplay.php?page='.$i.'&f='.$forum_id);
        //$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        //$items = $xpath->query('//ul[@id="threads"]/li[@id]');
    $items = $dom->getElementById('threads')->getElementsByTagName('li');
    foreach($items as $thread) {
    if(($id = substr($thread->getAttribute('id'), 7)) !== false)
    $ids[] = $id;
    }
}
    return $ids;
}
```

To get all the threads Ids from this forum, example of use:

```
$tids = GetIds("67",1,2); //Get all the Ids from page 1 to 2.
foreach($tids as $data) {
$file = fopen("threads.txt", "a+");
fwrite($file, "{$data}:");
fclose($file);
}
```

When i run the code i get this error:
**Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\eProject\functions.PHP on line 145**

line 145:

```
$items = $dom->getElementById('threads')->getElementsByTagName('li');
```

What is the problem?

Comment: can you post getElementsByTagName() please.

Comment: what did you mean by post getElementByTagName()?

Comment: $dom->getElementById('threads') is not returning an object. That is what it means.

Comment: I think this is asking for the wrong thing. getElementsByTagName() is failing because the result of getElementById() does not appear to be returning a valid object. Dump the return from getElementById('threads') into a temp variable and see what it is actually returning.

Comment: How can i fix this problem? its worked before and suddenly not.. help me please..

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the redirection.

```
http://www.example.com/forumdisplay.php?page=1f=67
```

evaluates into

```
http://www.example.com/forumdisplay.php?f=67
```

thus in the first url extracting

```
$items = $dom->getElementById('threads')
```

returns NULL instead of the relevant object.

You should be refering to a static url, also turn on warning errors for the test purpose

---

When got deep into the problem, I realized that the target site given probably started using Incapsula in order to prevent DDoS attacks, which stops unwanted requests.

In this cases, the target is expecting certain headers, in order to allow the request.

Unfortunately, I cannot give the exact information that the site is expecting, maybe you should examine it.

I found a discussion about what probably sites using Incapsula are expecting: http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=685567&show=20

Comment: This is not correct. The code as written would not resolve to the string you have analyzed. The code should produce the string ending with "forumdisplay.php?page=1&f=67" which appears to behave as intended. Second, even if the issue you raise were happening, the reevaluated url shown returns a valid default page in the expected format. In the example case, the failure you propose should manifest as the loop ignoring page number and repeatedly indexing the default page (page 1).

Comment: I still dont get it.. i use getElementById because the thread ids are located in:
    `<ol id="threads" class="threads">`

and the id itself located in:
`id="thread_********"> //******* is the ID number`

and than i use substr to get just the number without the "thread_":
`substr($thread->getAttribute('id'), 7)`

can you please tell me more about the problem? i really try to understand.. thanks in advnace!

Comment: @KentButler if you make a curl/file get contents to the given URL you will see that the output is not the one the OP is expecting (and not the one that you can see, when you open the url and click view source)

Comment: @RoyalBg can you fix my code and tell me what was wrong?

Comment: @user3546872 I get deep into the problem, and it seems to be because of request prevention, when I extract the source of the URL via cURL, I realized that your site seems to have started using Incapsula. You should examine your target, which is probably expecting certain headers in order to allow requests. Check this http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=685567&show=20

Answer (score 0):

A direct pull of the URL is not directly returning the desired content (h/t RoyalBg). This is not an issue with your code - there is nothing malformed about the requests it produces and it should correctly process the desired content were that content being returned.

It appears that the web site you are trying to scrape no longer allows pages to be directly accessed in the way your script is attempting to access them. The site now feeds a script to the browser (some of which is obfuscated) that apparently handles loading the content.

The solution is to write additional code to deal with the scripting and correctly ask the server to send you the desired content. My gut instinct is that one purpose for the change is likely to prevent their site from being scraped. If so, having this script break is likely to be a situation that arises consistently from here on out.

Comment: How can i find the script that this site use to prevent the site from being scraped?

Comment: The script is in the returned data when the URL is pulled directly with a curl request. There are resources online to deal with rendering the script human-readable and analyzing how it works; there may even be resources that directly address scripting for the system that has been implemented (Incapsula?).